# How to correctly implement lazy loading in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code (while trying to replicate code structure in https://danijar.com/structuring-your-tensorflow-models/ )

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Model:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self._output = None

    @property
    def output(self):
        if not self._output:
            weight = tf.Variable(tf.constant(4.0))
            bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(2.0))
            self._output = tf.multiply(self.x, weight) + bias
        return self._output

def main():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    model = Model(x)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        output = sess.run(model.output, {x: 4.0})
        print(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

gives an error. A part of it is as follows:

```
Caused by op 'Variable_1/read', defined at:
    File "example.py", line 27, in <module>
        main()
    File "example.py", line 23, in main
        output = sess.run(model.output, {x: 4.0})
    File "example.py", line 12, in output
        weight = tf.Variable(tf.Variable(tf.constant(4.0)))

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
```

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: Why do you define `weight` as `tf.Variable(tf.Variable(tf.constant(4.0)))` as opposed to `tf.Variable(tf.constant(4.0))`?

Comment: It was a mistake. Corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the call to `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` happens **before** the variables are created, in the first call to `model.output` on the following line.

To fix the problem, you must somehow access `model.output` before calling `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`. For example, the following code works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Model:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self._output = None

    @property
    def output(self):
        # NOTE: You must use `if self._output is None` when `self._output` can
        # be a tensor, because `if self._output` on a tensor object will raise
        # an exception.
        if self._output is None:
            weight = tf.Variable(tf.constant(4.0))
            bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(2.0))
            self._output = tf.multiply(self.x, weight) + bias
        return self._output

def main():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    model = Model(x)

    # The variables are created on this line.
    output_t = model.output

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        output = sess.run(output_t, {x: 4.0})
        print(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```