# OOM when using image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Hi I'm using `image_dataset_from_directory()` to load images(528x528) which are quite large and my model is also quite large. I have about 20k images. The problem is that I expect `image_dataset_from_directory` would load the required images lazily and not keep them into memory unless they are used currently. But in the middle of the first epoch I get a OOM error even though I have 56 GM of RAM. This means that the images are still getting loaded into memory. Can someone clarify how to make it load them lazily only for the current batch? I'm using Tensorflow-GPU 2.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly implement lazy loading in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097616/how-to-correctly-implement-lazy-loading-in-tensorflow)

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Hi I want to use this function I don't want to implement it from scratch

Comment: in that case you have to wait for someone to answer...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `image_dataset_from_directory` you can use `flow_from_directory`.

Here is a small example of code.

Code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

In the `ImageDataGenerator` you can specify the preprocessing steps. For complete set of options see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#expandable-1).

After this, you can use its `flow_from_diectory` method to load the images as and when required. For complete options see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory).

Note that the label names are inferred from subdirectory names present inside the target_directory.

Comment: in using flow from directory if you still get an OOM reduce the batch size

Comment: @AniketBote It's not really appropriate to ask another user to mark your answer as accepted, maybe unless he said _"This solved my problem!"_, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @NicolasGervais can you please join this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220781/asking-for-acceptance-upvote). I have a few things which I would like to ask.